# What is this plant with red-pink lines/veins on its big green rounded leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, plant-care

My mother bought this plant but she didn't bother to even ask what was its name and what type of care does it need. Can any of you identify it, so that we can find info about the proper care it should be given?

[image]

It tends to stand up still in the night but leaves come down during day. I'm saying this partly in case it helps to identify it and because if you know its name, you probably know if this behaviour is expected. Anyway just giving its name would be enough and very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the Prayer plant ([*Maranta leuconeura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maranta_leuconeura)), named because the way the leaves fold up at night is reminiscent of hands held together in prayer. This particular plant is *M. leuconeura var. erythroneura*, which has the prominent red veins and white spine on the leaves shown in your photographs.

Care tips:

- They're native to the tropics so they don't like cool temperatures.
- They also like a humid environment. Mist them regularly to keep the humidity up.
- Keep the soil moist at all times. They don't like to dry out. You can reduce watering a little while they're dormant during winter.
- They like mid- to bright light. I have one next to a south-facing windowsill and it seems quite happy.
- They can be susceptible to spider mites. See [How do I identify and control spider mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/how-do-i-identify-and-control-spider-mites) for more information.