# Are this spiders killing this trumpet tree?

Tags: spider-mites

I have a trumpet tree in a pot in my balcony. It has beautifully blossomed this spring and gave dozens of flowers. But since all the flowers fell down 1 month ago it has gotten worse and worse.

The leafs started loosing it's green color (see the pictures). Some of the bigger ones started dropping off.

It was then that I noticed some very small cobwebs and looking hard I started to see very tiny white spiders all over the tree. I proceeded to spray the whole tree with an insecticide I have that, according to the label, is appropriate against spider mites. It didn't get better but it also didn't get worse.

Yesterday I was watering the plant and it lost 5 or 6 leafs just for a little shake of the pot. I noticed again the spiders, this time many more than before, so I sprayed them again. This morning I found 15 more leafs on the ground.

Could this spiders be responsible for this? How can i get rid of them? It is also worth mentioning that I usually water the plan with hard tap water, is this bad as well?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is a bad case of spider mites.  They are sucking the circulatory fluid out of the plant.  You need to treat this right away with 5 ml soap mixed in 1 liter of water.  Best success is to wet a rag with the solution and brush the leaves.

See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/how-do-i-identify-and-control-spider-mites) for more detail.

Comment: What's a trumpet tree?

Comment: @Bamboo by the book it is Campsis radicans but I suspect this is an allamanda cathartica.  Either way that's a whole lot of spiders....

Comment: Sure is - but when I looked up trumpet tree it gave me four other plants, without a mention of Campsis - just curious as to what it might be, no doubts about the diagnosis

Comment: @Bamboo from the bits I can see, I'd go with [Brugmansia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brugmansia).

Comment: @Stephie Nice ID ! would be nice to have more pictures to confirm.  If correct this plant is poisonous

Comment: @kevinsky, in German the Brugmansia is often (incorrectly) referred to as "trumpet tree" (Trompetenbaum). Not to mention the mixup with Datura. But I have currently three of them on my patio...

Comment: Brugmansia and Datura were 2 of the plants listed as 'trumpet tree'...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will treat tomorrow morning with no more delay, it has lost even more leafs , there a not so many left now, looks very sad.

Comment: By the way, I think @Stephie is right, the Burgmansia in that picture looks exactly like the one I have, and the Germans here call it indeed "Trompetenbaum". Thanks for puttin it a name :)