# What is happening to my Areca Palm?

Tags: trees, palm

What is happening to my Areca Palm? Here are two pictures.
The right one is of my Areca Palm before I bought it from the shop and the left image is how it looks now.

After I brought it to my home it started to wither and the leaves turned brown and then black. Then I removed the dead leaves

Did I overwater it? Does it want more light?   Can I save it?

[image]

[image]

maybe the poor light in my room

Comment: Do you remove excess water from the black container?

Comment: Do not water the plant daily, constantly wet soil leads to virus fungus bacteria

Answer (score 1):

The usual problems are too much water, not enough light and possibly spider mites.

- move the plant closer to direct light
- let the top inch of soil dry out before watering thoroughly. Do not let the plant sit in water
- check the underside of the leaves for what looks like grains of salt.  If any are seen these are spider mites.  Details on treatment can be found [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/23708/499)

Comment: I water it once every week but It began to die then I water it from day to day
now I buy a meter maybe it will help me to know why this palm is dying 
the meter give me PH /Light/Moist levels
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnFdr.jpg

I see spider web?