# Spider web covering all my plants

Tags: houseplants, bugs, spider-mites

My plants have this condition that it is covered by a spider web all over my plants like a film. Are these spider mites? Where do they come from and how do I get rid of these?

Close up:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this webbing really close to te plant? It looks more like stretched across branches?

Comment: You may want to check out our other posts tagged [tag:spider-mites], especially [this one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/how-do-i-identify-and-control-spider-mites).

Comment: That looks like an ordinary spider web to me. All those green-coated wires have built a spider hotel, but they are completely harmless so leave them in peace, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether those are spider mites or not.  This plant appears to be a [Hawaiian scheffelera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schefflera_arboricola).  It has thick leaves with a waxy coating and are not normally subject to spider mites.  Here are my recommendations

- remove the dead leaves at the bottom of the pot. They will not compost inside and are a potential home for pests
- verify that the plant is not sitting in water.  It appears to be a pot-in-pot system and this can happen if you water too much
- remove the wire.  This plant is not a good bonsai subject as the leaves do not diminish in size.  If a branch is in the way just trim it back.  It responds well to pruning with new growth that can bud off old wood
- get a cloth soaked in 5 ml dish soap to one liter of water and wipe the webs off.  Repeat on the top and bottom of the leaves.  Then give it a rinse in the shower to get the soap off.  Repeat twice more at five to seven day intervals.  This should control most soft bodied insects.

Comment: It's an olive tree.

Comment: @thadeuszlay Olive trees do not grow well indoors and have quite a different bark.