# Indoor Cat Palm Browning/Yellowing

Tags: palm

I got my first indoor cat palm about 3 months ago. At first it seemed to be doing ok, but it started rapidly browning at the tips, and then entire leaves would yellow. There was another very helpful post on here where someone explained about spider mites, overwatering, and other factors! Since then, I did determine it had spider mites and have been checking regularly to make sure they do not return and treated it with need oil. I also rinsed it off in the shower before hand to shake it out. I also cut off dying leaves at the trunk as instructed.

I water it once a week, and lately I’ve been waiting until it gets dryer than that. It doesn’t get too much sunlight, so I’m thinking that could be part of it. I’ve also seen posts that say the soil and the water hardness could be a problem. I live in DC and Google says our water is “moderately hard” and I had used Miracle Gro Indoor Potting Mix. I thought it was improving because it’s been growing new stems, but I’m seeing that they are showing early signs of browning at the tip. Does anybody have any advice? I’ve included one photo where it usually is in the apartment, and other by the window for better light. [image][image]

Comment: I think I see spider mites on the leaves. See here for how to identify and remove https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/23708/499

Comment: Ok, I’ll go ahead and follow the steps in the link and see if it helps. Let me know if anyone else has any other suggestions!

Comment: And thank you, btw!

Answer (score 1):

I find that shallow watering causes browning at the tips. When watering I put mine in the sink and water them heavily, or you can actually sit the pot in some water until the soil is soaked.

Comment: How often do you water them like that then?

Comment: I don't water mine on a schedule. I just wait until the soil looks a bit dry, but some plants like to be kept moist. Here's a good resource on browning tips: https://www.pennington.com/all-products/fertilizer/resources/how-to-save-brown-tipped-plants

Comment: When I first started buying pots my mum told me "they like a good soak". I didn't listen to her and I always had problems with brown ends. When I started doing this the problem fixed. Better advice might have been "they hate shallow watering". There is still a little bit on some leaves that you only notice when you go up close, but most are healthy and the plants are thriving. I hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many palms like humidity, spray your leaves with water. Also palms mostly live in sandy soils, well drained if you over water with no drainage you can flood kill them.
They grow in forest understories so indirect sunlight and good humidity keeps them alive.

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you for the advice!